# Change hovertext for meta votes?

Tags: feature-request

Meta-Votes are different; they often refer to agreement or disagreement. However, the hovertext still says stuff about research and clarity. This can be confusing to new Meta users.

Can we change the hovertext for meta-votes to something like

> You agree with what this post has to say; it would be a good addition to the site.

Comment: Since it is a feature across SE, you might better propose it in Meta

Comment: Remember that some meta-posts can still be questions o_x. Need an ultra-generic sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No**

As L.Dutch mentioned, the hovertext is a *network wide* tag. Without changing the code, it can't be changed on a per-Stack basis and getting consensus for what that new text should be across the entire network would be... interesting.

**You're point is well taken, but what really needs to happen (IMO) is for participants on Meta to clearly explain what they think and up-vote or down-vote will mean in the context of their post**

And this applies to both questions and answers. Though I'm far from consistent myself about this, I've taken the time to explain in some posts what I expect an up-vote or a down-vote to mean. Doing so does change participants' behavior, because sometimes "I agree with what this post has to say" isn't the intent of the post.